# How to change property of a specific CSS pseudo element?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I am trying to add a specific color to a specific pseudo element that is shown 6 times throughout the page but I just can't seem to select that specific element (I have no problem selecting all the :after elements, though).

First, my JSFIDDLE [**is here**](http://jsfiddle.net/doss1/36fd2tpq/).

The "triangle" you see here is what I am trying to colorize:

[image]

Here's the CSS Code that handles the triangle's color:

```
.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:after {
border-left: 14px solid #fff;
}
```

Obviously, if I change the color from #fff to #333, it will affect ALL of the triangles on the page. My question is....how do I only affect a specific triangle? My goal is to change the color of each triangle on the page (in this case, 6 different triangles). I tried to assign an ID to the triangle like so:

```
#triangle1 .timeline > li > .timeline-panel:after {
border-left: 14px solid #333;
}
```

and then adding the ID in list tag in the HTML code like so:

```
<li id="triangle1">
```

But, that didn't work. Do I need to be more specific? Is there a better way? JQuery?

Comment: When you add an `id` to the `li` the selector should be `.timeline > li#triangle1 > .timeline-panel:after`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect, use `li#triangle1 > .timeline-panel:after {}`. `li` is the element that has your id, not one of the `ul`'s ancestors.

Comment: I forgot to ask...what would be the difference of doing your method vs li#triangle1 .timeline-panel:after {} as they both seemed to work equally. Thanks.

Comment: `a > b` is [**child selector**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators), means **a** is **b**'s parent; `a b` is [**descendant selector**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators), means **a** is **b**'s ancestor (parent, grandparent, etc.). In your case they match the same element, so both work.